# Capacitor: Unable to load capacitor.config.json

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, config, capacitor

Creating an Ionic 5 app with Capacitor, I'm running into this problem where it seems that `capacitor.config.json` is not being loaded.

This problem came after I've installed `@codetrix-studio/capacitor-google-auth`, before the project was running on android fine.

```
{
  "appId": "com.luyou.clauncher",
  "appName": "c-launchpad",
  "bundledWebRuntime": false,
  "npmClient": "npm",
  "webDir": "www",
  "plugins": {
    "SplashScreen": {
      "launchShowDuration": 0
    },
    "GoogleAuth": {
      "scopes": [
        "profile",
        "email"
      ],
      "serverClientId": "xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com", // On my project I'm using the real server client id
      "forceCodeForRefreshToken": true
    }
  }
}
```

On the android studio the build goes okay but when you try to open the app, it does crash with the following:

```
D/Capacitor: Starting BridgeActivity
E/Capacitor: Unable to load capacitor.config.json. Run npx cap copy first
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: capacitor.config.json
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.nativeOpenAsset(Native Method)
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:874)
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:851)
        at com.getcapacitor.FileUtils.readFile(FileUtils.java:148)
        at com.getcapacitor.CapConfig.loadConfig(CapConfig.java:121)
        at com.getcapacitor.CapConfig.loadDefault(CapConfig.java:85)
        at com.getcapacitor.Bridge.<init>(Bridge.java:152)
        at com.getcapacitor.Bridge$Builder.create(Bridge.java:1160)
        at com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity.load(BridgeActivity.java:73)
        at com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity.init(BridgeActivity.java:54)
        at com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity.init(BridgeActivity.java:37)
        at com.luyou.clauncher.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
D/Capacitor: Registering plugin: WebView
D/Capacitor: Registering plugin: AdMob
D/Capacitor: Registering plugin: GoogleAuth
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.luyou.clauncher, PID: 11477
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.luyou.clauncher/com.luyou.clauncher.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONArray.length()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONArray.length()' on a null object reference
        at com.codetrixstudio.capacitor.GoogleAuth.GoogleAuth.load(GoogleAuth.java:47)
        at com.getcapacitor.PluginHandle.load(PluginHandle.java:95)
        at com.getcapacitor.PluginHandle.<init>(PluginHandle.java:59)
        at com.getcapacitor.Bridge.registerPlugin(Bridge.java:464)
        at com.getcapacitor.Bridge.registerAllPlugins(Bridge.java:419)
        at com.getcapacitor.Bridge.<init>(Bridge.java:164)
        at com.getcapacitor.Bridge$Builder.create(Bridge.java:1160)
        at com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity.load(BridgeActivity.java:73)
        at com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity.init(BridgeActivity.java:54)
        at com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity.init(BridgeActivity.java:37)
        at com.luyou.clauncher.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 11477 SIG: 9
```

`capacitor.config.json` is already on the root path of the project and doing `npx cap copy` or `npx cap sync` doesn't solve this problem, but actually is copying the www files. For some reason, the capacitor config simply is just not being copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like Capacitor alpha versions are broken, so gonig back to Capacitor 2.4.7 fixes the problem. The `capacitor.config.json` is loading correctly and the native plugins are loading fine.

Answer (score 1):

awesome, thanks @Adrian Legaspi.
Downgrading to capacitor 2.4.7 solved it for me.

This is what my package.json looks like:

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "@capacitor/android": "^2.4.2",
  "@capacitor/core": "2.4.7",
  ..
},
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "@capacitor/cli": "2.4.2",
  ...
}
```